# What is the spinor column vector for anti-up?

Tags: particle-physics

I've just been introduced to spinors. They've been described as these two-component column vectors where, for example, the spinor for up is 
$\left( \begin{matrix}
1\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$ , and down would be $\left( \begin{matrix}
0\\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$.

To answer a question about spinors which involves the spinor for anti-up, I tried googling what the spinor for anti-up would be, and on none of the links at all was there anything about 2D column vectors. Or anything else I recognised, just a lot of extremely complicated maths.

So I thought I'd try asking here: is there a column vector for anti-up and what is it? And are the things I'm talking about actually spinors? Because spinors seems to be something very different, according to google.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better what you mean by "anti-up spinor"?

Comment: Ah. Ok, I think I'm confusing two concepts here somehow, but that might be really tricky to untangle. If I have $|u\rangle = \left( \begin{matrix}
1\\
0
\end{matrix}\right)$, does that indicate an up quark with spin up? Or is it just a representation of an up quark? I assumed the latter (in the context of representations in group theory) and so thought there would be a different column vector for an anti-up. The name 'spinor' though in hindsight suggests the first is more likely.